# Check if only certain directories were updated via SVN in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

In our CruiseControl.NET setup, we automatically check out new code, build our program, install it, and have several regression tests run. However, not all checkins need to have our regression tests run (e.g. when help files are updated).

Is there a way in CruiseControl.NET 1.4.4.52 to detect if only a certain directory was modified? My end goal is to implement a true/false flag that will determine if our regression tests should be run based on the directories that have been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extension of Pedro offer is to build hierarchy of project using [Filesystem triggers](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filesystem+Source+Control+Block), and a [sync queue](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Queue+Configuration):

1. Root One project to update all tree (no actual build is specified in this project)
2. Build projects that have appropriate filesystem triggers
3. Test projects that have appropriate filesystem triggers (which are less then build projects). These must have lower priority in queue than the build projects.

HTH

Comment: This seems like the most intuitive solution, I think this is the route I will take when I update our build server configuration this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your source control block as type [multi](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Multi+Source+Control+Block), you can specify any number of folders to monitor.  The only downside is it will no longer pull other source, but I'm assuming you don't care about the help files for the continuous build.

Clarification:

Currently, you likely have one source control block, which pulls all of the files under the specified folder.  If you switch to a multi block, you have to specify each of the folders you need separately.

If you still wanted the help files as part of a build, for example, but didn't want them to actually trigger the build, you would have to add an extra task to pull the help files before doing a compile.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will no longer pull other source"?

Answer (score 0):

if the helper files not required for continuous integration , it is better not commit that helper files.add those files to ignore list.

Comment: IMO, Build server considerations should not affect whether a file is a part of source control or not..    
Specifically, help files do need to be part of tree.

Comment: if its updated and part of the project means it should be a part of continuous integration and has to be updated for each build